# Properly aligning directlabels with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am absolutely new to `directlabel` + `ggplot2` package. So, I'd appreciate any help. I want to properly align my labels for the linegraph--I've spent hours trying to learn `directlabel`, and I think with SO's help I can make this work.

Here's my data:

```
structure(list(Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("American Gymnastics", 
"American Swimmers", "Boxing", "European Gymnastics", "Running"
), class = "factor"), Calendar.Quarter = structure(c(16071, 16161, 
16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 
17075, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 
16801, 16892, 16983, 17075, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 16436, 
16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 17075, 16071, 16161, 
16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 
17075, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 
16801, 16892, 16983, 17075), class = "Date"), Randomized.Viewers = c(49, 
45, 51, 55, 47, 48, 54, 57, 53, 50, 52, 58, 32, 29, 33, 40, 34, 
36, 31, 39, 37, 30, 35, 41, 5, 1, 25, 46, 38, 4, 56, 27, 21, 
43, 42, 44, 2, 59, 3, 10, 60, 7, 14, 24, 13, 16, 17, 28, 15, 
6, 19, 23, 11, 12, 20, 22, 9, 8, 18, 26)), .Names = c("Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team", 
"Calendar.Quarter", "Randomized.Viewers"), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, I wrote the following code to plot a simple linegraph:

```
d<-ggplot(data = p, aes(x=Calendar.Quarter,y=Randomized.Viewers)) +
       geom_line(aes(color = Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team))  +
       scale_color_manual(name = "Sports Type",values = c("blue", "gray51","gray51","gray51","gray51"),guide = FALSE)
 direct.label(d, list('last.qp', cex=.75,dl.trans(x=x-3)))
```

I used the following reference guide for `maxvar.qp` http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/docs/

The output of this graph is:[image]

As we can see all the points have moved to the left. While the top-3 lines seems to be okay, but "Running" and "Boxing" have moved a lot.

I have two questions:

a) Is there anyway I can place labels on top of linegraphs and toward the end of the linegraph, especially for "Running" and "Boxing"? I read this thread [Labelling points with ggplot2 and directlabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258075/labelling-points-with-ggplot2-and-directlabels) but I wasn't quite sure what's going on---I am a beginner with R have started using R only for about 2-3 weeks. My hypothesis is that the poster is using for loops, but I have too many rows in my actual data, and I want to stay away from for loop. I am looking for vectorized operation, if possible.

b) From this thread [How to use custom names for labels with ggplot2 + directlabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531960/how-to-use-custom-names-for-labels-with-ggplot2-directlabels), it seems that `DirectLabels` package takes values from Column names of the table. Is there anyway I can modify the label names? `ggplot2` provides an API for this. However, I am not sure whether `directlabels` has such API as well. If not, I would use `colnames` to overwrite the column names before calling `directlabel` function. I'd appreciate any thoughts on this.

*PS: I am asking two questions because I strongly believe they are related to the same data and problem. In the past, I have been criticized for creating multiple questions on the same dataset. So, I'm using my best judgment here.*

Comment: Names are taken from factor levels which you map to color. Function `levels()` can modify names for you.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thanks for your help. I've two questions: a) Is `levels()` provided by `directlabel`? b) Can you please help me with the first question, if possible?

Comment: `levels` is a base function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) Is there anyway I can place labels **on top** of linegraphs and **toward
>   the end** of the linegraph [...]?

For example,

```
direct.label(d, list('last.qp', cex=.75, hjust = 1, vjust = 0))
```

gives you

[image]

> b) [...] Is there anyway I can **modify the label names**?

For example

```
d + geom_dl(
  aes(label = letters[1:5][p[,1]]), 
  method = list('last.qp', cex=.75, hjust = 1, vjust = 0)
)
```

gives you

[image]

The mapping is

```
cbind(levels(p[,1]), letters[1:5])
#      [,1]                  [,2]
# [1,] "American Gymnastics" "a" 
# [2,] "American Swimmers"   "b" 
# [3,] "Boxing"              "c" 
# [4,] "European Gymnastics" "d" 
# [5,] "Running"             "e"
```

You can adjust it as you wish.